# Excel - If cell A = 'yes', enter 'x', else use data validation to restrict entry

Tags: excel, validation, if-statement, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to combine an IF statement with data validation in MS Excel.

I have a row of cells (A1, A2, A3... etc).

If the value of these are "No", then I want the values in the column below to be "x". If the values are "Yes", then I would like the values below to allow entry in date format only.

Is there a way I can do this by entering an IF statement into the Data Validation 'custom' setting?

Appreciate any information.

Comment: Conditional Formatting is what you're looking for

Comment: No. Conditional Formatting is not what I am looking for.

Comment: maybe both as Data Validation can't change cell value (well Conditional Formating can't either, but it can fake it)

Comment: The question said "below to allow entry in date format only", you can use either data validation or Format Cells. Conditional Formatting had this option **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**.

Comment: I don't understand how this would place an 'X' in the cell when it's 'NO' and leave it restricted for entry by a user if it is 'YES'.

Comment: What should happen if the data in B1 (for example) isn't a date and A1 is YES?

Comment: If A1 is a YES, then A2:A10 should be restricted to date entry only. If A1 is a NO, then A2:A10 should allow text. The problem with conditional formatting is that it doesn't restrict non-conforming entries.

Comment: I am thinking something along the lines of data validation using:

=IF(A$1="YES",Function which allows date entry only", "do nothing")

..if that makes sense.

Comment: OK, so I have worked it out as best as I can without the use of macros.

I used the following formula and it gets me as close to the desired effect as I need:

Data Validation formula:

=IF(A$1="YES",ISNUMBER(A2:C10),ISTEXT(A2:C10))

This restricts YES columns to numbers (which include dates), and restricts NO columns to text (which allows entry of 'X' or N/A.

Answer (score 1):

In one of your comments you said:

> If A1 is a YES, then A2:A10 should be restricted to date entry only. If A1 is a NO, then A2:A10 should allow text.

So you want it to always accept values - you just want the values to only be restricted when the cell at the top of the column contains "No"

To turn on Data Validation you could use VBA.  Add this function to Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 Then ' if the value changed is row 1
        If UCase(Target.Value) = "NO" Then ' if the entry is "NO"
            ' delete and readd the data validation
            Columns(Target.Column).Validation.Delete
            Columns(Target.Column).Validation.Add _
                 Type:=xlValidateDate, _
                 AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                 Operator:=xlBetween, _
                 Formula1:="1/1/2000", _
                 Formula2:="1/1/2100"
        Else ' if the entry is not "NO"
            ' delete the data validation
            Columns(Target.Column).Validation.Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.
Update after seeing your comments.

```
=IF(A$1:C$1="YES",A2:C10<=TODAY(),A2:C10="X")
```

To ally only dates before or equal to TODAY(). Then you can combine this with a conditional formatting to display it as "dd/mm/yyyy" like :

Formula:=A$1="YES" ; Format="dd/mm/yyyy" ; Applies to =$A$2:$C$10